# In LTSpice, when using hierarchal schematics, is it possible to display more than 4 sub-block parameters?

Tags: ltspice

In LTSpice sub blocks can be passed parameters using the "value", "value2", "SpiceLine", and "SpiceLine2" fields. When creating symbols for these blocks you can make each of those 4 visible on the symbol, so you can easily see and edit parameters from the parrent schematic. If you ant to pass more than 4 parameters you can by putting a log line into one of those fields like entering "var2=3 var3=10" into "value" will pass both parameters to the sub block, but this looks messy in the parent schematic when you have a lot of things to possibly edit as parameters for the sub-block.

I can do (for an example block)
Cesr=1m Cesl=3n
C0=1u Cm=10n
A=0.1148 B=47.873u C=2.321

But would like to do
Cesr=1m
Cesl=3n
C0=1u
Cm=10n
A=0.1148
B=47.873u
C=2.321

Is it possible to have more than just 4 parameter strings in a symbol? If so, how?